# Blaschke product is proper holomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory

I have to prove finite blaschke products are the examples of proper holomorphic maps of the unit disc into itself.

I know formal definition of proper map so I took any compact set on $\mathbb{D}$ and try to prove it's preimage is compact. I have no idea how to do it.

I think it may be very trivial but no idea. Any help?

Comment: The pre image is closed in $\mathbb D$ by continuity. Try to show it must be contained in some $\overline {D(0,r)}, r<1.$

Comment: @zhw. I think it is not obvious. Could u do for me?

Comment: So is the exercise to show that $f$ is proper iff $f$ is a finite Blaschke product? My comment only addressed $\impliedby$

Comment: yes you are correct. I know one way I only asking another way